# H2 database with JAX-RS(jersey)

Tags: java, hibernate, jersey, h2

I am trying to build simple REST api having simple endpoints doing CRUD operations. I am JAX-RS implementation jersey here. For DB part I want to connect to the in-memory database h2.

When I hit the endpoint I get empty body, with status 200 ok as I have set in response, but body doesn't show anything. I don't see any errors in the console after hitting the endpoint.

This is my Dao class

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import com.shrikant.jersey_restapp.model.Employee;

public class EmployeeDao {
    
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("my-persistence-unit");

    public void saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(employee);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
    }

    public Employee findEmployeeById(int id) {
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Employee emp = em.find(Employee.class, id);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        return emp;
    }

    public List<Employee> getAll() {
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        List<Employee> list = em.createQuery("from Employee").getResultList();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        return list;
    }
    
}
```

and this is my persistence.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="my-persistence-unit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>com.shrikant.jersey_restapp.model.Employee</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:h2:mem:demo" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
            <property name="show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults"
                value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

service

```
@Path("/company")
public class EmployeeController {
    
    private EmployeeService employeeService = new EmployeeService();
    
    @GET
    @Path("/empall")
    public Response getAllEmployee() {
        return Response.status(200).entity(employeeService.findAll()).build();
    }
    
    @GET
    @Path("/emp/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getEmployee(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        Employee emp = employeeService.getEmployeeById(id);
        return Response.status(200).entity(emp).build();
    }
    
    @POST
    @Path("/emp")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        employeeService.addEmployee(employee);
        return Response.status(200).entity("Entity saved").build(); 
    }
}
```

As you can see I have also set the show_sql property to true but I don't see any sql in the console either.

I might be missing something here, because I am not sure if h2 will start automatically. But I have also started h2 using h2.**.jar and connected to it, and still same response. Using first h2 with jersey

Don't understand what's going wrong, does anyone know what I am missing or what's going wrong ??

Thanks

Comment: Where is your JAX-RS service?

Comment: @stdunbar I have added it, you can check

Comment: @stdunbar can you see what's wrong ?

Comment: Based on what you're saying and the code you're showing I don't think your query is working correctly.  I would do some debugging - what does `employeeService.findAll()` return for example?

Comment: @stdunbar , it returns empty response

Comment: So your code is doing exactly what it says it is.  JAX-RS gets an empty object to send and it does just that.  You'll need to debug why your query isn't returning what you expect.  It might be a database issue, it may be the data inside of your database.

Comment: @stdunbar  I don't understand why it happening, am I missing any configuration in persistence.xml or how will h2 start ? will it start automatically or I'll have to start manually with using h2 jar, I tried both ways same response . And I tried to debug it, all db related object like emf and em are created properly. Tables are also not created when use jar, I might be missing something or I am trying to connect somewhere else

Comment: You'd get an exception if the database wasn't there.  Have you inserted any data?

Comment: @stdunbar I tried that. No response